# Scala generics - Why scala returns an instance of supertype instead of the subtype when type constraint is used?

Tags: scala, types, casting, programming-languages, scala-generics

I'm trying to transform y into something which can be appended to x, where x is a sequence of some sorts.

```
scala> def foo[U <: Seq[T], T](x: U, y: T): U = x :+ y
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[T]
 required: U
       def foo[U <: Seq[T], T](x: U, y: T): U = x :+ y
                                                  ^
```

I have the following solutions:

```
def foo[T]( x : Seq[T], y:T) = x :+ y
def foo[T]( x : Seq[T], y:T) : Seq[T] = x :+ y
def foo[U <: Seq[T], T](x: U, y: T): U = (x :+ y).asInstanceOf[U]
```

But my doubt is why the original one didn't work. It looks like if I apply an operator (`:+` in this case) defined in the super class then it returns the super class? i.e if `U` is a `Vector`, `foo` returns `Seq`, so I'm getting error `required "U" but found "Seq[T]"`.

Can anyone enlighten me why this behavior is seen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When coming across type problems, I usually adopt the "if it passes the compilation, what will happen" logic to find the unreasonable part.

In your case, assuming the original one is Okay.

```
 def foo[U <: Seq[T], T](x: U, y: T): U = x :+ y
```

cause Seq[T] is covariant on T, so the following case stands.

```
 for type A, T, if A <: T, List[A] <: Seq[T]
```

Then we can do the following operation:

```
 class Parent 
 class Child extends Parent

 // List(new Child) :+ (new Parent) => List[Parent]
val result = foo(List(new Child), new Parent)
```

U is actually List[Child] in the foo method, but when List operates with a different type from its element type, it will try to find the common parent, in this case result is typed with List[Parent], but the required type is List[Child]. Obviously, List[Parent] is not a subtype of List[Child].

So, the thing is the final type is elevated but the required type is a subtype of the elevated type.
If you look at the definition of Scala SeqLike, this may be clearer.

```
trait SeqLike[+A, +Repr] extends ... {
    def :+[B >: A, That](elem: B)(...): That = {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good stuff, I understand it now and what you say makes sense. Thanks a lot

Comment: I had a follow up question. What if I change `T` to some base class like `Nothing` or `Int`? At least then the compiler should be able to concur that I won't be passing a parent? `def foo[U <: Seq[Nothing], Nothing](x: U, y: Nothing): U = x :+ y`. Is this a type inference limitation?

Comment: @zapstar Nice follow-up, I guess you just make a presumption on the prerequisite that scala.Nothing is the bottom type in the Scala Hierarchy but lower bound U <: Seq[T] can just guarantee U is a subtype of Seq[T] or just Seq[T], not exactly Seq[T]. 
In your follow-up, what if we extends Seq[Nothing] with MySeq. Again, that falls into the case I mention in the answer. So, this is may not the thing about type inference limitation.

Answer (score 2):

Lets simplify this example

```
  class T
  class B extends T

  def bar[U <: T](x: T): U = {
    new B
  }
```

This won't compile, cause when you call

```
bar(new T)
```

you should return type T, but you're trying to return type B. B is subtype of T, but you should return exectly U, but not just a subtype if T.

You can fix your problem  by

```
def foo[U <: Seq[T], T](x: U, y: T): Seq[T] = x :+ y
```

or

```
def foo[B >: Seq[T], U <: Seq[T], T](x: U, y: T): B = y +: x
```

Comment: Yes I know, my question is why cannot my return type be of type `U` in this case?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on "This is because U do not include Seq[T]"

Comment: This was my error, I understood know, will try to explain in a minute

Comment: Thank you for your time, @Allen's answer was more clear to me.